# ARM assembler: bad immediate value for offset

Tags: c, arm

I am using GCC crosscompiler to compile to an ARM platform. I have a problem where, using opitmization -O3 gives me a "bad immediate value for offset (4104)" on a temp file ccm4baaa.s. Can't find this file either.

How do I debug this, or find the source of the error? I know that it's located somewhere in hyper.c, but it's impossible to find it because there is no errors showing in hyper.c. Only the cryptic error message above.

Best Regards

Mr Gigu

Comment: Which version of the compiler?

Comment: If the .s temporary assembly file is the one created by the compiler en route to creating the object file, then it sounds like a bug in the compiler.  I would get the exact version/variant info about your GCC compiler & search the "known bugs" for that version (or search for fixed bugs in later versions, assuming you don't have the latest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been similar known bugs in previous releases of GCC. It might just be a matter of updating your version of the GCC toolchain. Which one are you using currently?

Comment: If I remember right, GCC is up to it's 4.6.0's. I'd upgrade your toolchain.

Comment: Yes, you are indeed using a very old toolchain. Try this one from CodeSourcery:http://www.codesourcery.com/sgpp/lite/arm/portal/subscription?@template=lite

Comment: Recently switched to the codesourcery toolchain and I get the same error. No idea whats happening.

Answer (score 0):

In order to debug the problem and find the offending source, in these cases it helps to add the `gcc` option `-save-temps` to the compilation. The effect is that the compiler keeps the intermediate assembly files (and the pre-processor output) for you to examine.